# How to loop over object properties with ngFor in Angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, loops

I can write data by `keyValuePipe` or `{{data | JSON}}` but I think that is not good solution for me. How I can write data differently? How I use for this example `Object.entries`, `Object.keys` or `Object.value`?

**Code with JSON in Stackblitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jn8snh?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: In your stackblitz project change the line to this
```<p>{{obj.key}} - {{obj.value | json}}</p>```

Comment: @anjnkmr I need write clear data without parenthesis

Answer (score 0):

Your object is considered as a dictionary in javascript.

You can loop over properties of your object as follow:

```
<div *ngFor="let property of data">
     <p>{{ property }} - {{ data[property] }}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I have still  problem with write clear data and write this error: Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

Answer (score 0):

You can't to do that out of the box. [NgForOf](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#description) allows iterating over a collection, and by default object does not implement required methods and properties. In theory you could get the keys of the object by writing something like this:

```
<p *ngFor="let property of Object.keys(object)">
  {{property}} {{object[property]}}
</p>
```

But the way the contents of ngFor are evaluated, the global variable `Object` is not present in the scope. So you're best off writing a custom pipe that would do the work for you by transforming your object into iterable of your choice that is suitable for your requirements (not idea what that would be since the only information is that "keyValuePipe or {{data | JSON}} is not good solution for me" without any reasoning).

Comment: To use `Object` in the template you just need to add `Object=Object` to the components .ts file. This creates a public class level variable named Object which has the value of the the global Object and can be seen by the template.